# Virtualbox “Callee RC: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG” (0x80040154)?

Tags: virtualbox

I was getting the Virtualbox problem

> Callee RC: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG” (0x80040154)

all of a sudden. Problem started on VirtualBox 4.3 (I think). I upgraded to version 5 hoping to fix it but had no luck at that point.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your solution as an answer to your own question, instead of as a comment. There is no need to mark the question as solved by changing the title, just accept your own answer instead.

Comment: Thnx Anders, turned it into an Answer!

Comment: Run the Oracle Virtualbox app as Administrator and the error should go away.

Answer (score 33):

My solution:
Check your directory `C:\Users\yourname\.VirtualBox\` (`yourname` is in fact your username.)

On my PC there was a `VirtualBox.xml` with size of 0 Kb. 
Also there was a `VirtualBox.xml-prev` with a size of 3 Kb. 
Dates where somewhere around the time the problem started...

Renaming the `VirtualBox.xml-prev` one to the `VirtualBox.xml` SOLVED my issue.

For those without an xml file, here is my xml file, hopefully it helps .....

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- ** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. ** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application ** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect. ** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes. -->

-<VirtualBox version="1.12-windows" xmlns="http://www.innotek.de/VirtualBox-settings">


-<Global>


-<ExtraData>

<ExtraDataItem value="general,system,previewClosed,display,storage,audio,network,usb,sharedFolders,description" name="GUI/DetailsPageBoxes"/>

<ExtraDataItem value="m=59397901-1440-48ea-8781-6f86d06c7fbb" name="GUI/GroupDefinitions/"/>

<ExtraDataItem value="m=Sharepoint" name="GUI/LastItemSelected"/>

<ExtraDataItem value="415,153,770,550,max" name="GUI/LastWindowPosition"/>

<ExtraDataItem value="D:/virtualbox" name="GUI/RecentFolderHD"/>

<ExtraDataItem value="D:\virtualbox\Sharepoint.vdi;" name="GUI/RecentListHD"/>

<ExtraDataItem value="334,1261" name="GUI/SplitterSizes"/>

<ExtraDataItem value=",confirmGoingScale,remindAboutAutoCapture,remindAboutMouseIntegration,showRuntimeError.warning.HostAudioNotResponding,confirmInputCapture,warnAboutInaccessibleMedia" name="GUI/SuppressMessages"/>

<ExtraDataItem value="53" name="GUI/UpdateCheckCount"/>

<ExtraDataItem value="1 d, 2015-08-19, stable, 5.0.0" name="GUI/UpdateDate"/>

</ExtraData>


-<MachineRegistry>

<MachineEntry src="D:/virtualbox/Sharepoint/Sharepoint.vbox" uuid="{59397901-1440-48ea-8781-6f86d06c7fbb}"/>

</MachineRegistry>


-<MediaRegistry>

<HardDisks/>

<DVDImages/>

<FloppyImages/>

</MediaRegistry>


-<NetserviceRegistry>


-<DHCPServers>

<DHCPServer enabled="1" upperIP="192.168.56.254" lowerIP="192.168.56.101" networkMask="255.255.255.0" IPAddress="192.168.56.100" networkName="HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"/>

</DHCPServers>

</NetserviceRegistry>

<SystemProperties exclusiveHwVirt="false" LogHistoryCount="3" webServiceAuthLibrary="VBoxAuth" VRDEAuthLibrary="VBoxAuth" defaultHardDiskFormat="VDI" defaultMachineFolder="C:\Users\yourname\VirtualBox VMs"/>

<USBDeviceFilters/>

</Global>

</VirtualBox>
```

Comment: You can accept the answer yourself. That way, you can show other users that this is in fact a solution to your stated problem. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217589) for details.

Comment: Can only accept my own answer in 2 days it says :-(, so will do later on :-)

Comment: Having the same problem. I checked the location on my own unit. I didn't find both .xml files, only present are all .log file with number on them. How should I resolve this?

Comment: Added my xml file contents. Hope you can at least start virtualbox now and configure from there.

Comment: thank you. deleting existing `VirtualBox.xml`  and renaming `VirtualBox.xml-prev` to `VirtualBox.xml` fixed the problem

Comment: Removing the VirtualBox.xml with zero size and renaming the .xml-prev to .xml also worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

I had the error...

> Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient COM object. 
>   The application will now terminate. 
>   Callee RC: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG (0x80040154)

...when starting VirtualBox as normal user. Starting as administrator 
worked on the other hand.

System: Windows 8, VirtualBox 5

Actually, the issue "suddenly" appeared after I played around with raw disk accesses. During these test, I re-installed VirtualBox as administrator.

What people not always know is that the registry has also an access right management, like files. Right-click on a folder to access the Autorisations window to display them.

When I re-installed as administrator, the registry keys where created with an admin level access. By this, I wasn't able anymore to start VirtualBox as non-admin.

Re-installing as normal user did not solve the problem. Probably because some admin-level keys could not be deleted.

Solution that worked for me:

- Back-up *.VirtualBox* (optional, as all backups are :-)
- Uninstall VirtualBox
- Open Registry Editor regedit.exe as administrator.
- Delete all remaining VirtualBox keys (especially the .NET, driver registrations, Compatibility Manager settings)
- Reinstall VirtualBox using a user account.

Notes:

I did not test escalating the VirtualBox uninstaller process to administrator level with sysinternals. That might work as well.

Be careful with regedit. The GUI is quite '90s. Good to know: CTRL+F searches below the currently selected key, so be sure to go to the top when start searching.

I had one key for an USB driver that I wasn't able to delete due to access rights problems. Finally, this was not needed anyway.

Please don't forget to change access rights on VirtualBox disk files when they have been created with VirtualBox running as administrator.

Answer (score 5):

Renaming the `VirtualBox.xml-prev` one to the `VirtualBox.xml` solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

After you upgrade to VirtualBox-5.0.8-103449 started getting error: Virtualbox "Callee RC: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG" (0x80040154)

No advice on the Internet did not help.

It helped only delete the entire contents of the folder **"C:\Users\"*user*"\. VirtualBox"** and then restart Oracle VM VirtualBox shortcut on the desktop.

Apparently when you remove the previous version of Virtualbox folder
**"C:\Users\"*user*"\.VirtualBox"** is removed.

As the contents of the folder should be removed manually after reinstalling VirtualBox, as well as in case of damage VirtualBox, for example due to lack of space on the hard disk.

Not to be confused with the folder **"C:\Users\"*user*"\VirtualBox VMs"**

This folder appears later, only after the establishment has a particular virtual machine.

sorry for machine translation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error was caused by a zero-byte truncated `VirtualBox.xml` in the user's `.VirtualBox` folder. I found out after downgrading to `4.x` and getting a more descriptive error message regarding a missing `<` tag.

Answer (score 0):

As I already [suggested on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/970676/494750), as of today (09/09/2015).

Upgrade to the new version that was released.You can find it [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

There have been some [changes](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) concerning the Windows 10 Problems.

Comment: Updating to the new release produces the same error for me.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is in the last paragraph.**

I happened to have a different cause for the same error message under VirtualBox 5.0.20. 

So I temporarily installed VirtualBox 5.1.10 which tries to analyse the situation and gives more info about probable culprit.

In my case the error message from VB 5.1.10 looked like following:

> Failed to instantiate CLSID_VirtualBox w/ IVirtualBox, but CLSID_VirtualBox w/ IUnknown works.
>   
> PSDispatch looks broken by the 'xxx' ({11B6009E-3F04-4478-A807-30FBD579FC07}) program, suspecting that it features the broken oleaut32.msm module as component {997FA962-E067-11D1-9396-00A0C90F27F9}.
>   
> We suggest you try uninstall 'xxx'.
>   
> See also https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316911 .
>
> Result Code: 
>   
> E_NOINTERFACE (0x80004002)
>   
> Component: 
>   
> VirtualBoxClientWrap
>   
> Interface: 
>   
> IVirtualBoxClient {d2937a8e-cb8d-4382-90ba-b7da78a74573}

Where **'xxx'** is here a placeholder name for a specific program name it mentions and suggests to uninstall. *(The specific name in my case is not important here)*.

So I did uninstall the specific program the new VirtualBox version accused, and after that VB started working again. Then I reinstalled the old VB version 5.0.20 I needed to continue using and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

After some researching I found [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/851227/virtualbox-4-3-20-stops-working-after-windows-update) with the step:

```
find C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv\VBoxDrv.inf right click and select Install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, I believe something corrupted whilst shutting down without correctly closing connections and I couldn't boot VB.

Tried all of the solutions above but none of them worked.

Without Uninstalling I went to the virtual box website and grabbed the most recent version and installed over the top and VB jumped into life.

Version 6.0.14 From 6.0.10